# The requested service has not been registered ! AutoFac Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I am simply trying to use AutoFac to resolve dependencies but it throws exception such as

> *The requested service 'ProductService' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide service
>   or use IsRegistered()...*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<ProductService>().As<IProductService>();

        using (var container = builder.Build())
        {
            container.Resolve<ProductService>().DoSomething();
        }
    }
}

public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I do lots of things!!!");
    }
}

public interface IProductService
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

What I have done wrong ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With the statement:

```
builder.RegisterType<ProductService>().As<IProductService>();
```

Told Autofac whenever somebody tries to resolve an `IProductService` give them an `ProductService`

So you need to resolve the `IProductService` and to the `ProductService`:

```
using (var container = builder.Build())
{
    container.Resolve<IProductService>().DoSomething();
}
```

Or if you want to keep the `Resolve<ProductService>` register it with AsSelf:

```
builder.RegisterType<ProductService>().AsSelf();
```

Comment: You seems to be right.But i have seen AutoFac first time in an open source project named by NopCommerce and they have been using reserve approach what you advise. And it was working too. 

For instance;


  builder.RegisterType<BackInStockSubscriptionService>().As<IBackInStockSubscriptionService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<CategoryService>().As<ICategoryService>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<CompareProductsService>

Maybe they did more than that I couldnt see.

Comment: @RyuKaplan in your comment I see no example for `container.Resolve`... however I don't think that in NopCommerce they changed anything regarding how Autofac works. If you are new to Autofac you should start at the official documentation: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: @nemesv, I have huge number of clases that contains XService implement IXService. e.g ProductService implement IProductService. Any way to register all of these types.